# Photo Competition 2021-06-07: Symmetry

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Symmetry

The photograph must display some form of symmetry.

This theme was suggested by [Maynard Case](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2127/maynard-case).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/124948/photo-competition-2021-05-24-symmetry?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on June 7, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Great Egret

Baylands Nature Preserve, March 28th 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

ISO 224, f/7.1, 1/2000

[image]

Comment: Speaking of symmetry, the photo title is *this close* to a palindrome...

Comment: Do you mean an anagram?

Comment: yeah. I was enjoying a drink. Oops. =)

Comment: How did you take this?!? I'm nowhere close to this level of photography. Sincere kudos to you!

Comment: Seeing that you live in San Jose, you could visit the [Baylands](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Baylands+Nature+Preserve/@37.4584329,-122.1149356,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x808fba479eee10bf:0x25224ba81c6e1739!8m2!3d37.4574977!4d-122.107554). There's always plenty of different birds there, and there's many opportunities to get excellent shots with a telephoto lens. Generally, the earlier in the morning you go, the more active the birds will be.

Comment: Been there, ain't done that.

Answer (score 9):

## Underpass

[image: underpass]

Panasonic lumix Gx1

London

F5.3

1/125

29mm

Answer (score 7):

[image]

## Old rusty fence post

Took this on a dog walk around the local farm. It's part of a long dry-stone wall with a rusty old barbed wire fence on top.

Location: Balruddery Farm, near Dundee, Scotland

Date: 2020-03-30

Camera: Panasonic DC-GX9, 12-60@12mm, f/3.5, 1/2000 sec, iso 200

Answer (score 6):

[image]

**End of The Line**

This photo was taken at the tail end of an adventure my friends and I took where we decided to take the Boston metro to the end of one of its lines and then explore what was around. Pictured is the road that takes up the entire width of a thin strip of land leading to the peninsula of Nahant, Massachusettes. With the bay on one side and the Atlantic Ocean on the other, the lamp posts that stretched the entire strip were beautiful in spite of the weather.

Canon EOS 7d Mark II

F5.625,
1/400,
46mm,
ISO 100

Answer (score 4):

[image]

## View over Loch Achray

Location: Loch Achray, Scotland

Date: 2019-03-31

Camera: Panasonic DC-GX9, 12-60@12mm, f/6.3, 1/400 sec, iso 200

Answer (score 3):

"Synchronized dozing", on the kitchen sofa, 2018-10-23, Sony DSC-H1, 7.2mm/3.2, 1/50s, in-camera flash.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Wild reflection

[image: Wild reflection]

- 29.07.2019, Huesca, Spain
- PENTAX K10D. ISO 100 28mm f/8 1/350

Answer (score 2):

## Classic Lines

[image: Classic Lines]

The nameplate and grill of an old Chevy that has been heavily modified into a hot rod.

Answer (score 2):

### Empty local 6 train

[image]

October 2020, Pixel 4.

Comment: On a tangentially related note, I went into Manhattan (first time in a year) to pick up a new tripod last week... 5:00pm on a Friday and there were 19 people in my car on the Uptown 6 train.

Answer (score 2):

## Sunset

[image: Sunset]

Location: Weitsee, Reit im Winkl, Germany

Date: June 2020

Camera: Nikon D3100, 18-55mm @ 18mm, 1/500s, f11, ISO 100

Answer (score 2):

**Reflecting Pond**

Japanese Tea Garden, San Antonio, TX, USA

2021/01/03

Canon EOS 5D Mark IV + EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM @ 105mm

1/200, f/5.6, ISO 100

[image: Japanese Tea Garden]

Answer (score 1):

### Wave Tube

December 21st 2020

Canon Rebel T1i 1/1000, f/11, ISO 800

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Title: Room with a View.
Taken in Myrtle Beach, SC in April 2009.
Camera - Canon PowerShot SX10 IS.
Settings - f/4.5 at 1/500 sec, ISO 80

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Wait for me

[image: Wait for me]

- 1 August 2019, [Parque nacional de Ordesa y Monte Perdido](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ordesa+y+Monte+Perdido+National+Park/@42.5645946,-0.1523599,10.51z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0xd57f97fef4bbd47:0x67660d37ea442976!8m2!3d42.6468705!4d0.0349001?hl=en)
- PENTAX K10D. ISO 100 28mm f/6.7 1/250